# What parameters does TeamCity pass to MSBuild under the covers?

Tags: msbuild, azure, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I just downloaded TeamCity 7 today and decided to get it up and running for my Azure solution.  I am not trying to do anything fancy (yet) and started with a very basic command line build:

```
msbuild /t:Publish /p:Configuration=Release;TargetProfile=Production;PublishDir=S:\HoursTracker\Deployments
```

This builds successfully and produces a package that looks like this*:

[image]

I then attempted to configure TeamCity in an identical fashion:

[image]

This builds successfully and produces a package that looks like this*:

[image]

What I don't understand is why there is such a huge discrepancy in the size of the MVC project.  Publishing directly from Visual Studio produces the exact same result as my MSBuild command so I'm convinced that TeamCity is the odd man out.  Since I assume TeamCity is not broken, can someone please educate me on how to properly configure it so that I get the expected output?

*I have renamed the package files with .zip so that the details were viewable for this post.

Comment: Learn Process Monitor and you can see what are the parameters passed to MSBuild easily, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ming's answer helped me solve the mystery.  After inspecting the contents of the zip files, I discovered the difference was that my MSBuild package contained bin and obj folders and the TeamCity package did not.

[image]

After making this discovery, I realized that I could specify multiple targets to MSBuild and prepended "Clean" to my targets switch like so:

```
msbuild /t:Clean;Publish /p:Configuration=Release;TargetProfile=Production;PublishDir=S:\HoursTracker\Deployments
```

As expected, this removed those folders.  So apparently, TeamCity specifies "Clean" implicitly for you.  Mystery solved.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure packages may be larger than we expect. You can rename the cssx file to zip and you will find out what’s inside the package. In addition to the web application’s usual files, there’re a bunch of Windows Azure files. For example, if you enable diagnostics, you will see a diagnostics folder, where you’ll find files used by Windows Azure diagnostics runtime.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.

Comment: Thanks, Ming.  I did not realize those were also zips.  I will try to inspect them and see what's going on.  I'll follow up with more info if I figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

Why you specified x64 for msbuild runner? Try selecting tools version as well. You have not specified /p:Platform parameter. Does publish task involve rebuild?

TeamCity starts msbuild with number of /p: parameters taken from " properties and environment variables " section, plus some well-known parameters like configuration name or project name.

Comment: I tried both x64 and x86.  Both with the same result.  I also did not specify the tools version because it was my understanding that the point of that setting is to target a different .NET version than that of the MSBuild version.  In any case, I also tried specifying 4.0 for that setting and it did not have any apparent effect.